# If..Else dont understand

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a large segment of code, and it all works, except when there is a user error.
There is a text box which a user must put a value in, and then click a button to update a table.

If the user leaves the box blank and clicks the button a msg box pops up asking them to fill in a value, if the box contains a value then a series of commands and SQL is run.

Unfortunately, when the box is left blank, the msg box pops up, but then the commands and SQL run anyway.

I guess I may just be missing something really obvious, but I cant get my head around it.  this is the block of code that is causing me problems...

```
If IsNull(Me.TxtStockValue) Then MsgBox "Please Select An Item To Update Stock And Ensure A Value Has Been Entered" Else:
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete1
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStory
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete2
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLUpdate
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

txtStockValue is the txt box which cannot be empty.  The else doesn't seem to be working the way I want.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: This is exactly the same problem that I already offered a solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514474/query-syntax-error/9514535#9514535. Furthermore, I strongly suggested that you used Execute, rather than RunSQL and set warnings. Is it your intention to ignore all advice and to keep posting questions until you get an answer that you feel is acceptable and allows you to avoid all thinking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this - in your version only the first statement (SQLDelete1) is part of the else, the rest is always executed.

```
If IsNull(Me.TxtStockValue) Then
    MsgBox "Please Select An Item To Update Stock And Ensure A Value Has Been Entered"
Else
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete1
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStory
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete2
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLUpdate
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End If
```